# How to use register storage class with typedef?

Tags: c, typedef

I want to do this:

```
typedef register unsigned int _newint;
```

Basically, a concise alias of `register unsigned int` as `_newint`.

But an error, "more than one storage class may not be specified," occurs, underlining `register`.

I want to know if I can do this or not; if yes then how?

Comment: `typedef` is considered as a `storage-class` by C standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to know if I can do this or not, if yes then how?

Both `typedef` and `register` count as storage classes, though that's somewhat of a technicality in the case of `typedef`.  You cannot declare any identifier to have more than one storage class, so the direct answer is no, you cannot do that.

You could conceivably use a macro instead of a `typedef` to achieve a similar effect:

```
#define _newint register unsigned int

void foo() {
    _newint x;
}
```

That is misleading, however, so you shouldn't.

More generally, you probably should not be using `register` storage class at all.  Modern compilers don't need your help to figure out which variables to store in registers, and `register` is just a hint, so the only notable effect is that you are prevented (by rule) from taking the address of an object declared with that storage class.

Comment: Yes, @AdrianMole.  Are you going somewhere with that?

Comment: why is that macro misleading ?

Answer (score 2):

Strange as it may seem, the `typedef` keyword is actually a storage class specifier (and, as the error message indicates, you can't have a second, `register` specifier in the same statement). From [this C11 Draft Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> ##### 6.7.1 Storage-class specifiers
>
> …
> 5     The **`typedef`** specifier is called a ‘‘storage-class
> specifier’’ for syntactic convenience only; it is discussed in 6.7.8.
> The meanings of the various linkages and storage durations were
> discussed in 6.2.2 and 6.2.4.

If, despite the wording in the above-quoted paragraph, you find this *inconvenient*, then consider *why* you want to add a storage class specifier to a `typedef`. Most likely, it will make for clearer code if you add the `register` specifier (or any other qualifier) to **actual variables**, when they are declared:

```c
typedef unsigned int _newint;

void foo(void)
{
    register _newint MyNewInt;
    //...
}
```

'Hiding' that `register` specifier in an alias may cause problems for future readers of your code, who then can't understand why adding a *different* specifier to a variable of that type causes problems.